# jgGrid doesn't respect my imgpath

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

I'm trying to use jqGrid, but it doesn't respect the imgpath, it always defaults to

```
"\themes\default\images"
```

I'm setting:

```
imgpath: "..\..\Content\themes\default\images";
```

But it doesn't respect that and uses the default path, am I missing something?

Comment: If that is supposed to be a parameter setting (not familiar with this plugin), that doesn't quite look like the right syntax as I don't think there would be a semi-colon after the value. It would be either a comma or an end bracket/brace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've downloaded by mistake an ancient version of jqGrid (v0.01) which everything was hardcoded, thats why it wasn't working.